# Repeating A Group Of Code, But Increasing Values

Tags: lua

Good Day.

I am trying to write quite a lengthy bit of script, and i would like to know if my life can be made easier.

Here is an example of what i'm writing:

```
-- Static Variable
chance = 49.5
nextbet = 0.00000010
base = 0.00000010
base2 = 0.00000010
a1 = 0
stage = 0
bethigh = false
a1b = 0
bigbalance = 0
bigloss = 0
bigbet = 0
counter = 0

function dobet()

counter += 1

--Increase this variable by 1 each time a number is rolled
a1 += 1

-- Check if last rolled number is less than, if true reset variable to 0
if (lastBet.roll < 1) then
    a1 = 0
end


--------------STAGES--------------
if stage == 0 then
    if win then
        stage = 0
        nextbet = base
        chance = 49.5
    else
        nextbet = base
    end
end

if stage == 1 then
    if win then
        stage = 0
        a1 = 0
        nextbet = base2
        chance = 49.5
    else
        nextbet = previousbet*1.02
    end
end

------------STAGE SETTINGS---------

if stage == 0 then
    if a1 >= (99/1*5) then
        stage = 1
        chance = 1
        nextbet = base2
    end
end
end
```

What i am hoping to achieve. Is to copy this section:

```
if (lastBet.roll < 1) then
    a1 = 0
end
```

And repeating it but increasing the numbers by 1 like below:

```
if (lastBet.roll < 1) then
    a1 = 0
end

if (lastBet.roll < 2) then
    a2 = 0
end

if (lastBet.roll < 3) then
    a3 = 0
end
```

Same would apply for the next section:

```
if a1 >= (99/1*5) then
    stage = 1
    chance = 1
    nextbet = base2
end
```

Where i would like to copy/paste this but also with increasing the numbers by 1:

```
if a1 >= (99/1*5) then
    stage = 1
    chance = 1
    nextbet = base2
end

if a2 >= (99/2*5) then
    stage = 2
    chance = 2
    nextbet = base2
end

if a3 >= (99/3*5) then
    stage = 3
    chance = 3
    nextbet = base2
end
```

This is not a question regarding the functionality of my script, it works as intended. But i need to make it a lot longer than this, and i'm asking if there is a way to repeat the portions of code, with a slight change in the values so that i don't have to type it all out manually.

Comment: Why is it you're checking a different variable each time?
What is the exact instance for the iteration?
How and where are values initialized?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is very likely a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  please explain which problem you actually want to solve.

Comment: I have adjusted my question to hopefully better portray what i am asking.

Comment: Also what version of lua are you using? There is no `+=` operator in lua.

Comment: @pschulz I actually have no idea... It is for a program called DiceBot.

+= seems to work fine in this case, it replaces having to type:

a1 = a1 + 1

Answer (score 0):

If you make the`aN` variable an array of `a`, then you could use a function for the first and a loop for the second.

```
function CheckLast(last, roll)
    if last.roll < roll
        a[roll] = 0
    end
end

for i=1,10 do
    if a[i] >= (99/i*5) then
        stage = i
        chance = i
        nextbet = base2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Between myself and a friend we figured it out.

The question here was how to replicate code because i did not know about arrays or adding functions.

For anyone else that stumbles upon this question, here is how we did it.

```
--defines static variables
chance = 49.5
nextbet = 0.00000010
base = 0.00000010
base2 = 0.00000100
stage = 0
maxChance = 99
previousBetWasFail = false
counter = 0
betHigh = false
losspercent = 0
turnaround = 0
turn = 0
first = 0
lossstreak = 0
bb = 0

targets = {}
for i = 0, 3300, 1 do
    targets[i] = 0
end


function resetAll ()
    nextbet = base
    stage = 0
    chance = 49.5
    losspercent = 0
    turnaround = 0
    turn = 0
    first = 0
    lossstreak = 0
end

function dobet()

    counter += 1

    if win then
        lossstreak = 0
    end
    for i = 0, 3300, 1 do
        targets[i] = targets[i] + 1
    end

    for i = 0, 3300, 1 do 
        if (lastBet.roll < (i/100)) then
            targets[i] = 0
        end
        if turnaround == 0 then
            if (targets[i] >= ((99/(i/100))*10)) then
                turnaround = 1
                nextbet = base2
                if turn == 0 then
                    chance = (i/100)
                    turn = 1
                end
            end
        else
            nextbet = (previousbet*((chance/50)+1))
            if win then
                resetAll()
            end
        end
    end
    if turnaround == 1 and first == 0 then
        nextbet = base2
        first = 1
    else
        if first >= 1 and turnaround == 1 then
            if !win then
                nextbet = (previousbet*((chance/50)+1))
            else
                resetAll()
            end
        end
    end
    if balance >= bb then
        bb = balance
    end
    print(balance)
    print(bb)
end
```